# getClass() in abstract class returns random implementation class

Tags: java, osgi

In an OSGi application I have a class hierarchy as follows:

```
public interface IA {
    public void someMethod();
}

public abstract class AbstractA implements IA {
    public void someMethod(SomeObject s) {
        System.out.println(this.getClass());
    }
}

public class ImplAA extends AbstractA {
    //Some other methods
}

public class ImplAB extends AbstractA {
    //Some other methods
}
```

The interface, the abstract class and the implementations are in 4 different bundles.
Another bundle contains a class looking like this:

```
public class SomeClass {

    private IA implAAInstance;
    private IA implABInstance;

    protected void bindToAA(IA ia) {
        implAAInstance = ia;
    }

    protected void bindToAB(IA ia) {
        implABInstance = ia;
    }

    protected void sendStuff(SomeObject p, SomeObject q) {
        implAAInstance.someMethod(p);
        implABInstance.someMethod(q);
    }
}
```

The methods `bindToAA` and `bindToAB` are the bind functions to bind to the bundles containing classes `ImplAA` and `ImplAB` respectively.
In the XML Component Definition this looks as follows:

```
<reference bind="bindToAA" cardinality="0..1" interface="path.to.IA" name="ImplAA" policy="dynamic"/>
<reference bind="bindToAB" cardinality="0..1" interface="path.to.IA" name="ImplAB" policy="dynamic"/>
```

In the bundles containing `ImplAA` and `ImplAB`, there's this essential line in the XML Component Definition:

```
<implementation class="path.to.ImplAA"/>
<service>
    <provide interface="path.to.IA"/>
</service>
```

and

```
<implementation class="path.to.ImplAB"/>
<service>
    <provide interface="path.to.IA"/>
</service>
```

The problem now is that when I run the code, there is printed twice that `ImplAA` is used.
What's the cause of this? And how can I make it print the right implementation class?

Comment: Lots of information missing. Are you publishing instances of ImplAA and ImplAB as services? You seem to be saying that `SomeClass` is a DS component, if so what does your DS declaration look like? As far as I can see so far, there is nothing wrong with the output. You ask for an instance of IA and ImplAA is one. What's the problem?

Comment: I editted the question, the exact problem is that I don't want some random implementation class of IA, I want exactly the one I bound to. I hope the question is more clear now

Comment: Have you tried this with normal java code by just using a Main method without OSGI and binding complications.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. The question @PeterKriens asks is very relevant. WHY do you insist on a particular implementation class? If you already know the class you want then you can just create it with the `new` keyword in Java. The point of services is to decouple you from specific implementation classes and instead focus on the contract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing wrong is not specifying the target in your xml file.

The solution would be to add a property to your class AA with the name type and value "aaa" for example and adjusting the bind reference in your xml file as follows:

```
<reference bind="bindToAA" target="(type=aaa)" cardinality="0..1" interface="path.to.IA" name="ImplAA" policy="dynamic"/>
```

Do the same for you other services, this way when you try to bind on a specific service of a group of services using the same interface, it can distinguish between them using the target/properties using an LDAP filter.

For more information on LDAP filters:
[Info on LDAP filters](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r2/org/osgi/framework/Filter.html)

Answer (score 3):

Well, you bind to IA ... and there are two IA services (ImplAA and ImplAB). So, why on earth would DS use a different service instance for bindToAA than it does for bindToAB? You only declared to require an IA?

Both bind methods require 0 or 1 IA instance so any of the two services matches the bill, in those cases it is better to take just one since the requirer (SomeClass) doesn't seem to care about the difference.

No the big question in my head is, why on earth would you want to depend on the instance? The whole purpose of OSGi is to keep instances hidden away. If you have a dependency requirement, then express this, this is the OSGi way.

No if you just want to print the services, make the cardinality MULTIPLE and put the services in a list. In that case you express the interest in ALL IA services.